# jQuery load txt file with arrays and format as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to take a .txt file with multidimensional arrays in it and load it through ajax and sort through the data and spit it out on my site. The data is only coming back as plaintext though and even when I use JSON.parse() on it nothing comes back.

I am using this to access the file:

```
$.get("json/json_data.txt", function(json) {

    json = JSON.parse(json);
});
```

The file looks like:

```
array(array('industry' => 'Advertising/Media',array( 
        'no_hover' => 0,
        'organization' => 'Marina Reef',
        'existing_url => 'http://www.alphasoftware.com/marina-reef-case-study.asp',
        'heading' => '<h3>Giant Touch Screen App</h3>',
        'description'  => 'Interactive brochure application running on a 46\" touch screen.',
        'logo' =>'marina-reef-sized.pmg',
        'large_image'  => 'marina-reef-large.jpg',
        'page_name'  => 'marina'        
    )),
      array('industry' => 'Construction/Engineering/Real Estate',array( 
        'no_hover' => 0,
        'organization' => 'Al Reyami',
        'existing_url => 'http://www.alphasoftware.com/al-reyami-case-study.asp',
        'heading' => '<h3>Enterprise-wide System for Invoicing, Financial Management, Inventory, Human Resources, and More</h3>',
        'description'  => 'Global construction firm uses Alpha Anywhere as its enterprise development and deployment platform, because it required less code than other tools.',
        'logo' =>'al-reyami-sized.png',
        'large_image'  => 'al-reyami-large.jpg',
        'page_name'  => ''      
    ))
);
```

Comment: Your file contains invalid JSON. If the json is not valid the parser returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file isn't JSON. You'll have to write a custom parser, or convert the file in to valid JSON. The problem is 'array' is being used for the purposes of arrays and objects; you'll have to totally manipulate the structure.

In addition, JSON needs double quotes for (most) things, and all of the instances of `=>` need to be changed to `:`...

TL;DR you need to end up with this, and it won't be easy:

`[{
    "industry": "Advertising/Media",
    "no_hover": 0,
    "organization": "Marina Reef",
    "existing_url": "http://www.alphasoftware.com/marina-reef-case-study.asp",
    "heading": "<h3>Giant Touch Screen App</h3>",
    "description": "Interactive brochure application running on a 46\" touch screen.",
    "logo": "marina-reef-sized.pmg",
    "large_image": "marina-reef-large.jpg",
    "page_name": "marina"
}, {
    "industry": "Construction/Engineering/Real Estate",
    "no_hover": 0,
    "organization": "Al Reyami",
    "existing_url": "http://www.alphasoftware.com/al-reyami-case-study.asp",
    "heading": "<h3>Enterprise-wide System for Invoicing, Financial Management, Inventory, Human Resources, and More</h3>",
    "description": "Global construction firm uses Alpha Anywhere as its enterprise development and deployment platform, because it required less code than other tools.",
    "logo": "al-reyami-sized.png",
    "large_image": "al-reyami-large.jpg",
    "page_name": null
}]`

*Alternatively*, you might want to use the 'industry' value as the 'key' for each identical entry, like so:

`{
    "Advertising/Media": {
        "no_hover": 0,
        "organization": "Marina Reef",
        ....
    },
    "Construction/Engineering/Real Estate": {
        "no_hover": 0,
        "organization": "Al Reyami",
        "existing_url": "http://www.alphasoftware.com/al-reyami-case-study.asp",
        ....
    }
}`

Either method will work, but it depends on how you intend to access the JSON object afterward.